# texture appears to be reading off uninitialized memory

Tags: c, opengl, textures, opengl-4

I create a texture like this:

```
GLuint tex;
unsigned char data[12] = {255, 255, 255,
                          255, 255, 255,
                          255, 255, 255,
                          255, 255, 255};

glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

I get the location of it:

```
GLuint texloc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex_map");
```

and then inside my drawing loop I have:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glUniform1i(texloc, 0);
```

and then inside my fragment shader I have:

```
out vec3 color;

uniform sampler2D tex_map;

void  main()
{
    .
    .

    color = texture(tex_map, vec2(-0.1, -0.5));

}
```

And sometimes when I run the program the object I am drawing becomes a random non white color, often red. I thought I had handled the out of bound case by using `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. What is causing this behavior?

EDIT: this behavior also occurs when both values inside `vec2(_, _)` are inside the range of 0-1...

Comment: A wild guess would be that any of the object (texture, shader) creation code is called outside of the scope of the OpenGL context. Double check, that there's a valid context active on the current thread when doing this stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

The default alignment is 4 bytes but your `data` array is assuming tight packing.

Comment: thanks this worked. I just want to share this link: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/197557-What-does-glPixelStore%28%29-do which also helped me understand what it means. TLDR: declaring your texture as an array of characters doesn't guarantee your array will have a memory address that is divisible by 4. If you create your texture array with ints then you don't have this problem